# Invoking class constructor by explicitly specifying type witness

Tags: java, generics

[Oracle docs on Java generics type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) gives this exmaple:

```
class MyClass<X> {
  <T> MyClass(T t) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

> Consider the following instantiation of the class MyClass:
>
> `new MyClass<Integer>("")`
>
> The statement explicitly specifies the type `Integer` for the formal type parameter, `X`. The compiler infers the type `String` for the formal type parameter, `T`, because the actual parameter of this constructor is a String object.

I tried to experiment with this. I defined following class:

```
class Box<T,S> 
{
    T item;
    S otherItem;

    <X> Box(S p1, X p2)
    {
        otherItem = p1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        /* Below gives compile time error:
           The constructor Box<String,Integer>(String, int) is undefined
        */
        Box box4 = new Box<String,Integer>("Mahesh",11);
    }
}
```

Above call to constructor gives me compile time error:

```
The constructor Box<String,Integer>(String, int) is undefined
```

I know I can do this by specifying the diamond:

```
Box box4 = new Box<>("Mahesh",11);
```

But just curious, how can I do this by ***explicitly specifying [type witness](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)***...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's why your code does not work.

By `Box<String,Integer>` you mean a `Box` type with the generic type parameter `T` being equal to `String` and `S` being equal to `Integer`. Right?

By replacing known generic arguments, the constructor's signature for `Box<String, Integer>` is:

```
<X> Box(Integer p1, X p2)
```

This is how you call the constructor:

```
new Box<String,Integer>("Mahesh",11)
```

You gave it a `String` as the first argument, but the constructor expects an `Integer`. Compiler Error!

You have lots of ways to work around this. Either swap the positions of the two generic type arguments, or swap the positions of the arguments when calling the constructor.

Comment: Also in case of calling constructor `<X> Box(X a)`, type witness specified will be that of `class Box<T,S>`, but not corresponding to the `X` in the constructor signature `<X> Box(X a)`. However, if I had method `private static <K> void printK(K a){}`, I have to make call as `Box.<Integer>printK(2)`, that is specify type witness corresponding to `K` in method signature. RIght?

Comment: @Mahesha999 no you put the type parameters after the method name. I am outside so I can't test whether putting it in front works.

Comment: I guess you understood it wrong. I was pointing to the fact that in case of invoking constructor, type witness is specified for class types (`class Box<T,S>`) (not constructor types `X Box(X a){}`), but in case of method invocation, type witness is specified for method types (`<K> void printK(K a){}`).

Comment: @Mahesha999 yes, every type parameter is optional, if you don't specify it, it defaults to `Object`

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question:

> how can I do this by explicitly specifying type witness...

You put in angle brackets between the `new` and the class name:

```
new <TypeWitnessForConstructor> Box<TypeArgumentsForInstance>(...)
```

But that is not the problem with your code, as Sweeper's answer shows.