# Specify repeated generic type in constructor?

Tags: java, generics, types, constructor

Suppose I have the following class:

```
import java.util.function.Function
import java.util.List

class Foo<X, Y> {
    public Function<X, Y> converter;
    public List<X> inputs;

    public Foo(Function<X, Y> converter, List<X> inputs) {
        this.converter = converter;
        this.inputs = inputs;
    }
}
```

I want to add a constructor that takes a `List<X>` of inputs and automatically supplies an identity Function to go along with it:

```
public Foo(List<X> inputs) {
    this(Function.identity(), inputs);
}
```

However, this gives me an error: `The constructor Foo<X, Y>(Function<Object,Object>, List<X>) is undefined`.
On the other hand, the following compiles:

```
public static <X> Foo<X, X> makeFoo(List<X> inputs) {
    return new Foo<>(Function.identity(), inputs);
}
```

In fact, the following also works:

```
public Foo(List<X> inputs) {
    this.converter = (Function<X, Y>)Function.identity();
    this.inputs = inputs;
}
```

However here I have to make an unchecked cast from `Function<Object, Object> to Function<X, Y>`. It will work, but I've learned that there is usually a way to deal with generics (or anything in Java) that doesn't require casting.

Is there a way to make the constructor work with this instead of resorting to a static method or casting?

I have tried calling the other constructor with `this((Function<X, X>)Function.identity(), inputs)`, rewriting the constructor as `public Foo<X, X>(List<X> inputs)`, as well as calling the other constructor with `<X, X>this(Function.identity(), inputs)` but nothing works.

It seems like there should be a way of letting the compiler know that the `Function.identity()` argument, or the `Foo` created, is of type `<X, X>`, but I can't come up with any good place to put it. I have looked around and cannot find a way to cast or specify the type in any way. The closest I can find related to the subject is type witnesses, "`BoxDemo.<Integer>addBox(Integer.valueOf(10), listOfIntegerBoxes);`" from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html), but that seems like a different scenario. There is also the interesting "`new <TypeWitnessForConstructor> Box<TypeArgumentsForInstance>(...)`" suggestion from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42730245/8245386) SO answer, but that also doesn't seem to apply. I think the reason neither apply is because my constructor does not have any type parameters such as `public <Z> Foo(...)`.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not a better way.  You can't restrict this constructor to only work when `X` and `Y` are the same types, so the constructor has to assume they're different, and that `Function.identity()` is correspondingly not necessarily the right type.

That said, using a static factory method is often better practice than exposing a constructor anyway, and if you do that you'll be fine.